# Python 3.5, how to remove the brackets and quotes from an element when printing or sending the value to a function?

Tags: python-3.x

I am reading a list of states from a file into an list[]:

```
 mystk = []
 with open('state_list.txt') as csvfile:
     readCSV = csv.reader(csvfile,delimiter=',')

for row in readCSV:
    mystk.append(row)
```

After the read I am adding the values in to a list.

```
print(str(mystk[0]).strip())      

i=0
while i < 10:
    strList = mystk[i]
    print('Print:',strList)
    i = i +1
```

The output of the above is :

```
 Print: ['AL']
 Print: ['AK']
 Print: ['AZ']
 Print: ['AR']
 Print: ['CA']
 Print: ['CO']
 Print: ['CT']
 Print: ['DE']
 Print: ['FL']
 Print: ['GA']
```

I am trying to achieve the following:

```
 Print: AL
 Print: AK
 Print: AZ
 Print: AR
 Print: CA
 Print: CO
 Print: CT
 Print: DE
 Print: FL
 Print: GA
```

I guess I could write a function or loop to strip out the ['?'] using regex or code like this:

```
i=0
while i < 10:
    strList = mystk[i]
    strList = str(strList).replace("['", "")
    strList = strList.replace("']", "")
    print('    ','Print:',strList)
    i = i +1
```

However I was hoping there was an easier way then the code above however I am new to python and if this is the only way then it works for me.

Comment: Why are you faffing around with strings? Use it as a list and access the first element.

Comment: if every line only has a single value then why use `csv`? why not just `mystk = csvfile.readlines()`? Or better yet: `for line in csvfile: print(..., line)` if all you want to do is print each line to the screen?

Comment: problem I am having with lists is that for some reason i am getting ['name']  passed / printed instead of just name to a function call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this are recommendations that I mention in my comment plus some other

```
import csv

def getTID(file='TID.csv', delim='\n'):
    result = []
    with open(file) as csvTID:
        readCSV = csv.reader(csvTID, delimiter=delim)
        for row in readCSV:
            result.append( row[0] )
    return result

stockList = getTID()
for x in stockList:
    print(x)
```

here with the use of arguments give the function more flexibility and with default values I retain the original behavior that way you don't need to modify your code (or the name of the file) if you want to use your function with another file like `'TID_2.cvs'` for example, in that case just call `getTID('TID_2.cvs')` and as the function don't do anything to some global variable you can have the data from 2 or more different files in different variables if you need it, for example

```
stockList1 = getTID('TID_1.cvs')
stockList2 = getTID('TID_2.cvs')
```

Answer (score 0):

every line of the csv file is split by commas, to get the string [`join`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/stdtypes.html#str.join)ed by commas again, use [`str.join`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/stdtypes.html#str.join):

```
sep = ", "
for row in mystk:
    print('    ', 'Print:', sep.join(row))
```

Answer (score 0):

Guys thank you all very much, learning this is stuff is awesome. So many ways to do stuff. After reading your comments and understanding the concepts I have written the following function to get the stock list I need:

```
import csv

stockList = []

def getTID():

    with open('TID.csv') as csvTID:
        readCSV = csv.reader(csvTID,delimiter='\n')
        for row in readCSV:
            stockList.append((row[0]))


getTID()

for x in stockList[:]: print(x)
```

This returns the list as expected: VOD.L, APPL, etc.

Comment: you don't need the `[:]` in  `stockList[:]` to be able to iterate over that list, also in general global variables should be used a constants, and modifications to object outside a functions is usually a bad practice that can bite you later on. Your function `getTID` should build that list inside it an return it, no modify the global one

Comment: Thank you all very much.